# How do I get the list of Users assigned licenses to my managed package in a subscriber org

Tags: apex, soql, managed-package, package

How do I get the list of Users assigned licenses to my managed package in a subscriber org based on the Package Name OR Package ID?

I do not want to use Package namespace, which is possible by querying UserPackageLicense object, because the namespace could be same for multiple packages in the packaging 2.0.
Query Example:

```
String APP_NAMESPACE_PREFIX = 'myNameSpace';
List<User> licensedUsers = [SELECT Name  FROM User WHERE Id in (SELECT UserId FROM UserPackageLicense WHERE (PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix = :APP_NAMESPACE_PREFIX)) ];
```

I think MetadataPackage object does has this info, but we are unable to query or use it in APEX. 
Any idea

Comment: Given that 2GP is not yet GA, I don't think you can build a future-proof solution for this today. It seems likely either the requirement will be that you need separate namespaces if you're licensing separately, or that the UserPackageLicense or PackageLicense objects will have additional fields exposed to be able to differentiate.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor that's what I'm thinking right now there is no other option to get the details correct?